# Sencha Touch dataGrid - sortable and serachable

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch

Hi I need to create an order and catalog system that contains items in a datagrid. That is the grid needs to be searchable and sortable. Data comes from remote xml files that are an export of a database. I then transform these into json representation.

I need to be able to edit (add orders) not just present them in the dataview. Is sencha touch able to handle such a complex UI?

I am able to do this in jQuery Mobile (mostly adapting jQuery UI plugins) but I would like to develop this in a maintainable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this grid in a few applications.. It is sortable and editable. I dont think its searchable out of the box, but could easily be added:
https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ext.ux.touch.grid